# Retrofit 2 and RxJava error handling operators

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I'm using Retrofit 2 in my project with Observable interface and the Result wrapper. Example:

```
@POST("api/login")
Observable<Result<LoginResponse>> login(@Body LoginRequest request);
```

I need the Result wrapper to obtain more information from the response than just the serialized object (for example headers, http status...).

Problem is, with the Result wrapper no exception is thrown by the network call. You can find the exception inside the result by calling Result.error().

What should I do if I want to take advantage of RxJava error operators?
For example, I'd like to use the retry operator on a network error, but the retry operator only works if an exception is thrown by the observable.

Comment: Look at the link http://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2016-03-16-retrofit2-rxjava-error-handling.html They describe how to override _RxJavaCallAdapterFactory_ in _Retrofit.Builder_ and there there for you may catch your objects in _Observable.onResumeErrorNext_ / _Observable.onDoNext()_

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with.
If I will improve it I will post the changes here.

The solution to my problem (exception swallowed by Retrofit and not handled by RxJava) is the **Observable.error** method that creates a new observable that only emits the error, so I can "rethrow" the exception.

I created an observable transformer to append to every rest call that emits a retrofit.Result.
This transformer takes an Observable> and, if the response has no errors, transforms it into an Observable>. If there are errors it returns an Observable.error with custom Http*Exceptions that I can later handle in my Observer in the onError callback.
I put it as a static method of an utility class called **ObservableTransformations.resultToResponseWithHttpErrorHandling**.

Here it is:

```
public class ObservableTransformations {

public static <T> Observable.Transformer<Result<T>, Response<T>> resultToResponseWithHttpErrorHandling() {
    return observable -> observable.flatMap(r -> {
        Observable<Response<T>> returnObservable = Observable.just(r.response());
        if (r.isError()) {
            Throwable throwable = r.error();
            if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
                Timber.e(throwable, "Retrofit connection error.");
                // TODO Check this cases
                if (throwable instanceof java.net.ConnectException) {
                    returnObservable = Observable.error(new HttpNoInternetConnectionException());
                } else if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    returnObservable = Observable.error(new HttpServerDownException());
                } else {
                    returnObservable = Observable.error(new HttpNoInternetConnectionException());
                }
            } else {
                Timber.e(throwable, "Retrofit general error - fatal.");
                returnObservable = Observable.error(new HttpGeneralErrorException(r.error()));
            }
        } else {
            Response<T> retrofitResponse = r.response();
            if (!retrofitResponse.isSuccess()) {
                int code = retrofitResponse.code();
                String message = "";
                try {
                    message = retrofitResponse.errorBody().string();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Timber.e(e, "Error reading errorBody from response");
                }
                Timber.i("Server responded with error. Code: " + code + " message: " + message);
                Throwable t = null;
                if (NetworkUtils.isClientError(code)) {
                    t = new HttpClientException(retrofitResponse.code(), message);
                } else if (NetworkUtils.isServerError(code)) {
                    t = new HttpServerErrorException(retrofitResponse.code(), message);
                }
                returnObservable = Observable.error(t);
            }
        }
        return returnObservable;
    }).retryWhen(new RetryWithDelayIf(3, 1000, t -> {
        return (t instanceof HttpNoInternetConnectionException) || (t instanceof HttpServerDownException);
    }));
}

}
```

The retry is made 3 times using an exponential backoff, and only if the exception is HttpNoInternetConnectionException or HttpServerDownException.

The **RetryWithDelayIf** class is here. It takes the condition to be met for retry as the last argument of the constructor (a function taking a throwable and returning true if this throwable should trigger the retry and false if not).

```
public class RetryWithDelayIf implements
    Func1<Observable<? extends Throwable>, Observable<?>> {

private final int maxRetries;
private final int retryDelayMillis;
private int retryCount;
private Func1<Throwable, Boolean> retryIf;

public RetryWithDelayIf(final int maxRetries, final int retryDelayMillis, Func1<Throwable, Boolean> retryIf) {
    this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
    this.retryDelayMillis = retryDelayMillis;
    this.retryCount = 0;
    this.retryIf = retryIf;
}

@Override
public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Throwable> attempts) {
    return attempts.zipWith(Observable.range(1, maxRetries + 1), (n, i) -> {
        return new Tuple<Throwable, Integer>(n, i);
    })
            .flatMap(
                    ni -> {
                        if (retryIf.call(ni.getFirst()) && ni.getSecond() <= maxRetries) {
                            return Observable.timer((long) Math.pow(2, ni.getSecond()), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                        } else {
                            return Observable.error(ni.getFirst());
                        }
                    });
}

}
```

Finally, here is the usage with a restService call:

```
restService.login(new LoginRestRequest(username, password))
                .compose(ObservableTransformations.resultToResponseWithHttpErrorHandling());
```

In the **onError** of your observer you can finally handle the Http*Exceptions.

Comment: Looks like a solution that might be helpful for my problem. Please see my question and maybe we can come up with a nice generic solution for the benefit of the community.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39437299/rxjava-retrofit-baseobservable-for-api-calls-for-centralized-response-handl

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the Throwable thrown is an instance of HttpException.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you didn't understand the problem. By the way, Retrofit 2 now throws a generic IOException if it cannot reach the server (no internet connection, server down..).